# Validating with DTD - connection forcibly closed

Tags: c#, xml, c#-2.0, dtd, xml-validation

I'm validating a document with the DTD in the document which is not on my machine, it is stored on the internet.

I am currently getting the following exception

```
System.Xml.XmlException: An error has occurred while opening external DTD 'http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd': Unable to connect to the remote server ---&gt; 
System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---&gt;
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 216.109.104.11:80&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket, IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&amp; exception)&#xD;&#xA;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)&#xD;&#xA;  
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenStream(Uri uri)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)&#xD;&#xA;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlValidatingReaderImpl.Read()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)&#xD;&#xA;   
at cXML.ResponseFactory..ctor(HttpRequest request) :: System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---&gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 216.109.104.11:80&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket, IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&amp; exception)&#xD;&#xA;   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)&#xD;&#xA;   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenStream(Uri uri)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId) :: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 216.109.104.11:80&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket, IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception&amp; exception)
```

I know the file is accessible as I can browse to it. But why cannot .NET access it?!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got following exception when i browse the  [http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd ] dtd file.

XML Parsing Error: syntax error
Location: http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.020/cXML.dtd
Line Number 15, Column 1:

Just download the dtd file and try to access the dtd locally. You can narrow down your problem.

Comment: That is what I have done in the end. I created a Resolver and then just told it to use a local copy.