# .NET: Preventing Web Access When Validating/Reading XML Schemas?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xml-validation

I'm trying to prevent .NET Framework accessing the Web when validating an XML document using XML schemas, because I don't want it to rely on having the Web access all the time. For this purpose I intentionally created local hard disk copies of all XSD's I'm using when validating, but it still fails when loading some these schemas.

For example, this piece of code fails (**but only if unplug my machine from the Web**):

```
using (Stream schemaStream = File.OpenRead(schemaFileName))
{
    XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaStream, ValidationCallBack);
    xmlSchemaSet.Add(schema);
}
```

The `schemaFileName` points to a **locally** stored copy of `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` file. The exception I get is

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.w3.org'
Status: NameResolutionFailure
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenStream(Uri uri)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy_PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.System.Xml.IDtdParserAdapter.PushExternalSubset(String systemId, String publicId)
at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseExternalSubset()
at System.Xml.DtdParser.ParseInDocumentDtd(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
at System.Xml.DtdParser.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.DtdParserProxy.Parse(Boolean saveInternalSubset)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.Schema.Parser.StartParsing(XmlReader reader, String targetNamespace)
at System.Xml.Schema.Parser.Parse(XmlReader reader, String targetNamespace)
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(Stream stream, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
```

I suspect it's still trying to load something from `www.w3.org`, possibly the DTD schema `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd`. **Is there any way to prevent this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it turned out to be simpler than I thought. This [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783615/validating-with-dtd-connection-forcibly-closed) gave me the lead (and refreshed my memory).

I already have my own implementation of `XmlResolver` for rerouting to my local copies of XSD files, but now I needed to use it for DTDs when loading XML schemas, too:

```
using (Stream schemaStream = File.OpenRead(schemaFileName))
{
    XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    xmlReaderSettings.XmlResolver = myXmlNamespaceResolver;
    xmlReaderSettings.ProhibitDtd = false;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(schemaStream, xmlReaderSettings))
    {
        XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, ValidationCallBack);
        xmlSchemaSet.Add(schema);                    
    }
 }
```

Then I needed to download a copy of http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.dtd and http://www.w3.org/2001/datatypes.dtd and now it works even without Web access.

Comment: Funny, I went with the same solution, but it was *less simple* than I thought.  I guess I figured you could somehow bypass this process altogether, especially since, in my case, I was not actually validating the documents but merely wanted to open them.

Comment: @harpo: hmmmm, if you're not validating them, then I think there **should** be a simpler way. Have you checked all of `XmlReaderSettings`? I think there's a way to tell it not to validate, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I tried everything I could think of, including `XmlReaderSettings`.  This was the only thing that worked (other than pre-stripping out the `DOCTYPE`, which could be just as bad, depending on the situation).

Comment: @Igor: Could you post your "entire" code anywhere ? Including the resolver. I tried to mix your solution with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422087/xmlresolver-xslt-compiler-error with no luck. Thank you