# C# Passing XML as Parameter to XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to insert some XML nodes (plus child nodes) into an XSLT transformed document. I have the XML as a string, and so at first I passed this string in and simply printed it. However, all the `<`s and `>`s were escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;` and so I realized that an XML parser would ignore these and not recognize the string as XML nodes.

I tried first writing the string to a file, and then loading it up using the document() function. However, this resulted in the error: `Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.` I also realized that due to the sensitive nature of the documents being transformed this could pose a serious risk, as anybody could write a file with whatever they liked to that location and it would potentially be picked up and inserted into the output XML.

So, I tried passing the XML in as a URI with `data:text/xml` appended to it, as the document function is supposed to be able to parse and load URIs of this kind. However, this has resulted in the same error: `Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.`

My `XslCompiledTransform` object is being instantiated correctly, as far as I know. XsltSettings are set to allow the document() function to be used, and I have passed in the XmlUrlResolver object.

```
            var xslt = new XslCompiledTransform(true);

            var resolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
#if DEBUG
            xslt.Load(Location, new XsltSettings(true, true), resolver);
#else
            xslt.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(this.Text)), new XsltSettings(true, true), resolver);
#endif
```

I am at somewhat of a loss here. Really, the ideal would be to have a way to pass in the string and tell the Transformation Processor not to escape the `<`s and `>`s. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Regarding "Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439036/xslloadexception-resolving-of-external-uris-was-prohibited. For the rest, please construct a minimum, self-contained runnable code sample along with the expected output. There are several ways to get new nodes into an XML document, [`ImportNode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.importnode(v=vs.110).aspx) being one of them. Why does it have to be XSLT?

Comment: @Tomalak I already saw that question. It is partly how I got to the situation I am in now.

Comment: ...and the other things in my comment?

Answer (score 4):

Use e.g.

```
XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(new StringReader(stringWithXml));
XsltArgumentList xsltArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
xsltArgs.AddParameter("param1", "", doc);

...
xslt.Transform(input, xsltArgs, output);
```

with C# and then `<xsl:param name="param1" select="/.."/>` in the XSLT to declare the parameter and initialize it as an empty node set, then you can use `<xsl:copy-of select="$param1"/>` to copy the XML to the result where you want to insert it.

Instead of an `XPathDocument` you could also use an `XmlDocument` or `XDocument` I think (might need to explicitly call `CreateNavigator()` and the latter).