# Problem with Powershell $xslt.Transform() and using the Document() function in xslt

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt

I have made an xslt script that translates an XML Peppol/UBL invoice to an xml format that can be imported into our ERP-system. The script worked perfectly in Powershell using the following:

```
$xsl=’ C:\temp\Axtension_UBL_TEST2.xslt’
$xslt.Load($xsl)
$xslt.Transform($_, $output)
```

until I decided to bring part of the script with the parameters of vendors outside script using the Document() function. I then received the following error:

***Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "Execution of the 'document()' function was prohibited. Use the XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction property to enable it.***

I then changed the powershell transform script to:

```
$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings   
$XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1   
$XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver   
$xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform;   
$xslt.Load($xsl, $XsltSettings,$XmlUrlResolver)   
$xslt.Transform($_, $output)
```

I now receive the following error and now I am stuck. Can somebody help me out?

***$xslt.Transform($_, $output)
Exception calling "Transform" with "2" argument(s): "An error occurred while loading document 'Vendors.xml'. See InnerException for a complete description of the error."***

Vendors.xml refers to filename in the xslt script used to load the file into the xslt. Both Axtension_UBL_TEST2.xslt’ and Vendors.xml are in the same folder and spelling (caps) are correct.

I do also not know how to make the complete error visible with InnerException.

This is a working part of the xslt script that generates the same error in Powershell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns:default="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2" exclude-result-prefixes="cac cbc ccts qdt udt default">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PurchaseInvoices_version_1.0>
            <xsl:for-each select="default:Invoice">
                <PurchaseInvoice>
                    <xsl:variable name="current-vendor-name" select="cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyName/cbc:Name"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="vendor-data" select="document('Vendors3.xml')/vendors/vendor[name=$current-vendor-name and administration='XYZ']"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="VendorShortName" select="$vendor-data/shortName"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$vendor-data"/> 
                </PurchaseInvoice>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </PurchaseInvoices_version_1.0>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Vendors3.xml file contains the following:

```
<vendors>
    <vendor>
        <administration>XYZ</administration>
        <name>TestVendor</name>
        <shortName>Tvendor</shortName>
        <accountNumber>20250</accountNumber>
        <invoiceType/>
        <IncludeOrderReference>No</IncludeOrderReference>
        <lineText>ItemName</lineText>
        <lines>Yes</lines>
    </vendor>
</vendors>
```

The xml used for input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Invoice xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ccts="urn:un:unece:uncefact:documentation:2" xmlns:qdt="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:QualifiedDatatypes-2" xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
  <cbc:UBLVersionID>2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
  <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:transaction:biitrns010:ver2.0:extended:urn:www.peppol.eu:bis:peppol4a:ver2.0</cbc:CustomizationID>
  <cbc:ProfileID>urn:www.cenbii.eu:profile:bii04:ver2.0</cbc:ProfileID>
  <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
    <cac:Party>
      <cac:PartyName>
        <cbc:Name>TestVendor</cbc:Name>
      </cac:PartyName>
    </cac:Party>
  </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
</Invoice>
```

The output when using an xslt editor like Oxygen gives the following output"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PurchaseInvoices_version_1.0>
   <PurchaseInvoice>
        XYZ
        TestVendor
        Tvendor
        20250
        
        No
        ItemName
        Yes
    </PurchaseInvoice>
</PurchaseInvoices_version_1.0
```

I used a TransformXML script (with ***$Xslt_Settings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1*** )  to do this and that seems to give more information about the error:  ***Resolving of external URIs was prohibited***

The InnerException is printed below:

```
SourceUri      : 
LineNumber     : 0
LinePosition   : 0
Message        : An error occurred while loading document 'Vendors.xml'. See InnerException for a complete description of the error.
TargetSite     : System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator GetDataSource(System.String, System.String)
Data           : {}
InnerException : System.Xml.XmlException: Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.
                    at System.Xml.XmlNullResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
                    at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase)
HelpLink       : 
Source         : System.Private.Xml
HResult        : -2146231998
StackTrace     :    at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryContext.GetDataSource(String uriRelative, String uriBase)
                    at <xsl:template match="/">(XmlQueryRuntime , XPathNavigator )
                    at Root(XmlQueryRuntime )
                    at System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument, XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter writer)
                    at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(String inputUri, String resultsFile)
                    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object , Object )
```

Comment: Is the `Vendors.xml` a well-formed XML document? Does Edge or Chrome or Firefox show any errors, for example, when you try to load it in a browser?

Comment: Also what do you use in the XSLT, `document('Vendors.xml')`? Try `document('Vendors.xml', document(''))` perhaps.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to say that the xslt script with the document() function works also perfecty using the Oxygen editor. It must be related to Powershell and not so much the xslt script itself.

Using document('Vendors.xml', document('')) did not make a difference to the Powershell error.

Comment: To  Martin Honne: I added the xslt script and the input/output as well as the vendors file. It is a well formed xml which is working in Oxygen and does not show errors in Oxygen.

Comment: Changing the document referemce from document('Vendors3.xml') to document('Vendors.xml',/) or document('Vendors.xml', document('')) also does not make a difference.

Comment: I think with e.g. `try { $xslt.Transform($_, $output)  } catch { $PSItem.Exception.StackTrace}` should show the stack trace or ``try { $xslt.Transform($_, $output)  } catch { $PSItem.Exception.InnerExceptionMessage}` the message of the inner exception.

Comment: The XmlResolver for the Load call might only be used for `xsl:include/xsl:import`, try passing an new XmlUrlResolver also to the `Transform` call.

Comment: Hi Martin, I think you are right. Appearantly it is not as easy to change $XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver to $XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlResolver. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I suggested to create an additional XmlUrlResolver (or you could use the same) but to use an overload of the `Transform` function that takes that explicit `Xml(Url)Resolver` argument, in the hope that allows the transformation to make the `document` call successfully.

Comment: Hi Martin, I cannot find what I have to do. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: In order to debug I would first try to print the Inner Exception you are getting. I would also try to pass a full path to the document() function to make sure the problem is not the resolver looking in a different path. (I think by default it looks for the XML file in the XSLT file directory.)

Comment: I added the InnerException-text. It fails to load the Vendors.xm that is in the xslt via the Document() function --> Resolving of external URIs was prohibited.

Comment: Assuming `$xsl`, `$_`, and `$output` are file string paths, I cannot reproduce your error using what you posted here: xsl, ps1, input xml, and external xml. Via PowerShell, I successfully render your output as shown (minus broken tag at end). Make sure your post is reproducible.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439036/xslloadexception-resolving-of-external-uris-was-prohibited?force_isolation=true

Comment: Which version of Powershell is that, is that using .NET framework or the new cross-platform one using .NET (Core)?

Comment: I use Powershell 7.2.5. I just tested it in Windows Powershell ISE using PS 5.1.19041 and it actually produced the output that I wanted. However in Powershell 7.2.5. it does not.

Comment: I just tested it on the server using Powershell 5.1 and it works. It is unsatisfactory that cannot get it working with PS 7 but so be it.

Comment: Deep down in the links of the previous .NET XmlUrResolver question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32439036/xslloadexception-resolving-of-external-uris-was-prohibited?force_isolation=true that @jdweng posted in an earlier comment there is some note of a change in .NET (Core) vs .NET framework and how to enable the previous behaviour with .NET C# code for .NET (Core), doing `AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Xml.AllowDefaultResolver", true);`. I can't tell whether that can be applied from Powershell or whether there are other ways.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I will dive into this this weekend (busy at work, just before my holiday) as it annoys me that it does not work on PS 7. I will post it if it works. I really appreciate your time spent on this question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `XslCompiledTransform` and its `Transform/4` method.  I had the same issue with PowerShell 7.4 and the following approach works for me.

```
$XmlUrlResolver = New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver
$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings($true, $true)
$XsltParams = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList
$XslInputElement = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform

$XSLWriterSettings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$XSLWriterSettings.Indent = $True
$XSLWriterSettings.IndentChars = "    "
$XSLWriterSettings.NewLineChars ="`r`n"
$XSLWriterSettings.Encoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding  $False
$XSLWriter = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("output.xml", $XSLWriterSettings)

$InFile = New-Object System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument("input.xml")

$XslInputElement.Load("transform.xslt", $XsltSettings, $XmlUrlResolver)
$XslInputElement.Transform($InFile, $XsltParams, $XSLWriter, $XmlUrlResolver)
```

Using `XsltSettings($true, $true)` is also important as it enables the use of the `document` function.

Of course the specific writer settings are irrelevant to this, but the key was to be able to use the version of `Transform` which accepts the URL resolver.  Also, using `XslTransform` instead of `XslCompiledTransform` seemed to fail silently and yielded an empty dataset in the transform.